# Injecting service in Grails3 script

Tags: grails

I have created a script in Grails version 3.2.8:

```
create-script my-script
```

In Grails 2 I could inject a service by using the **ctx** variable:

```
def myService = ctx.myService
myService.myMethod() //works
```

I tried doing the same in my Grails 3 script. But an error is thrown:

```
grails my-script
error: No such property: ctx for class: my-script
```

What is the correct way of injecting a service into a Grails 3 script?

Comment: it's same in Grails 3 as well. Have you tried using the grails console and see if the error exist there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

As stated in the [documentation for run-script](https://docs.grails.org/3.2.8/ref/Command%20Line/run-script.html)

*Groovy scripts intended to be executed this way cannot be located in src/main/scripts because that directory is reserved for CLI scripts created by create-script.*

In addition, the right command is:

*grails **run-script** /path/my-script.groovy*

To execute Groovy scripts in the context of a Grails environment.